# Pressing on main menu open the correct menu in the accordion sidemenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm trying to open the correct item in the accordion sidemenu after pressing on it in the main menu from the home page !!

I'm using this sidemneu 
https://github.com/tefra/navgoco

I tried to use `.hash` in jQuery & using the `.click` function & also the `trigger` function!! but it didn't work!

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    console.log("element was clicked"); // or alert("click");
});
$("#test").trigger("click");
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wC93j/ works fine for me

Comment: If you're 'using that [sidemenu]' put together a demo *using* that side-menu. Your posted code seems to bear no relation to your problem.